# create new dataframe field using lambda function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, list-comprehension

I am trying to create a new column based on conditions on other column.
(the data frame is already aggragated by user)
this is a sample of the data frame:

```
event_names                          country  
["deleteobject", "getobject"]         ["us"]
["getobject"]                         ["ca"]
["deleteobject", "putobject"]         ["ch"]
```

I want to create 3 new columns:
was data deleted?
was data downloaded?
did the events come from my whitelisted countries? 
WHITELISTED_COUNTRIES = ["us", "sg"]

like this:

```
event_names                      country  was_data_deleted?   was_data_downloaded?  whitelisted_country?
["deleteobject","getobject"]      ["us"]         True                 True                 True             
["getobject"]                     ["ca"]         False                True                 False
["deleteobject","putobject"]      ["ch"]         True                 False                False
```

This is what I tried so far:

```
result_df['was_data_deleted'] = result_df['event_name'].apply(lambda x:True if any("delete" in x for i in x) else False)

result_df['was_data_downloaded'] = result_df['event_name'].apply(lambda x:True if "getObject" in i for i in x else False)

result_df['strange_countries'] = result_df['country'].apply(lambda x:False if any(x in WHITELISTED_COUNTRIES for x in result_df['country']) else False)
```

I get an Error `"SyntaxError: invalid syntax"`

any ideas? thanks!

Comment: you missed small braces only in the middle statement , result_df['was_data_downloaded'] = result_df['event_name'].apply(lambda x:True if ("getObject" in i for i in x) else False), everything is working fine in existing implementaion.. or you can do it somewhat better code based on provided answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['was_data_deleted'] = df['event_names'].apply(lambda x: 'deleteobject' in x)
df['was_data_downloaded'] = df['event_names'].apply(lambda x: 'getobject' in x)
df['whitelisted_country'] = df['country'].apply(lambda x: x[0] in WHITELISTED_COUNTRIES)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                 event_names country  was_data_deleted  was_data_downloaded  whitelisted_country
0  [deleteobject, getobject]  [us]    True              True                 True               
1  [getobject]                [ca]    False             True                 False              
2  [deleteobject, putobject]  [ch]    True              False                False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your lambda function with remove `if-else` and `True, False`, because compared values already return it:

```
WHITELISTED_COUNTRIES = ["us", "sg"]

#checked substring delete
f1 = lambda x: any("delete" in i for i in x)
result_df['was_data_deleted'] = result_df['event_names'].apply(f1)

#checked string "getobject"
f2 = lambda x:"getobject" in x
result_df['was_data_downloaded'] = result_df['event_names'].apply(f2)

#checked list
f3 = lambda x:any(y in WHITELISTED_COUNTRIES for y in x)
result_df['strange_countries'] = result_df['country'].apply(f3)

print (result_df)
                 event_names country  was_data_deleted  was_data_downloaded  \
0  [deleteobject, getobject]    [us]              True                 True   
1                [getobject]    [ca]             False                 True   
2  [deleteobject, putobject]    [ch]              True                False   

   strange_countries  
0               True  
1              False  
2              False
```